# Power consumption of air conditioner

Tags: air-conditioning

[image]

Hey guys,

Can anyone please help me how to estimate the power comsumption of an air conditioner. I know it is hard to get the exact number due to the different conditions that the AC might be running at but I am only looking for a rough estimation in KWh. The two tables “Electrical cooling input + the cooling capacity” are confusing me. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: multiply 2kw by the duty cycle.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a rough estimate, then use the manufacturer's estimate (from the label) of 5014 kWh per year.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that on high cool it uses 2.149 kW electrical (agrees with 230 V x 9.5 A) continuously. So per day it would use 52 kWh if it were running continuously. If the unit is cycling on and off, then it would use less.